# Karate: checking value in array whether any of the value is blank or null

Tags: karate

Here is the sample json

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "hostname": "CDGRPASEAAR001",
      "critical": 0,
      "minor": 1,
      "syslog": 0
    },
    {
      "hostname": "MUMBCHUDAAR001",
      "critical": 0,
      "minor": 0,
      "syslog": 0
    },
    {
      "hostname": "",
      "critical": 0,
      "minor": 1,
      "syslog": 0
    },
```

I am trying below:

```
And match actualResponse == {result[2].hostname: '##notnull'}
```

But I am getting this validation message:

> reason: actual value has 4 more key(s) than expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you were trying for:

```
* match response.result[2] contains { hostname: '##notnull' }
```

This would also work:

```
* match each response.result contains { hostname: '#string' }
```

So please go through the docs: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#fuzzy-matching

If you are trying to find some count, then `match` is not what you want. You have to start doing transforms, like `filter()`. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74459339/143475 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/75425063/143475

For example:

```
* def names = response.result.filter(x => x.hostname !== '').map(x => x.hostname)
* match names == ['CDGRPASEAAR001', 'MUMBCHUDAAR001']
```